# Makefile: converting multiple .dot files to .png

Tags: makefile

I'm fairly new to makefiles so please don't be to harsh. :)

My problem is that I want to convert all .dot files in the directory of the makefile to .png files.
Usually this command should solve my problem:

```
DOT_FILES=$(wildcard *.dot)
DOTPNG=$(DOT_FILES:.dot=.png)
...
...    
dot: $(DOT_FILES)       
     @dot -Tpng $(DOT_FILES) > $(DOTPNG)
```

.. but it doesn't. It seems that it is converting all files but also overwriting them. So all I get is 1 of 3 .png files and this error:

```
Error: dot: can't open graph.png
Error: dot: can't open example.png
Makefile:35: recipe for target 'dot' failed
make: *** [dot] Error 3
```

Am I doing something wrong or isn't this the code I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your files are `foo.dot`, `graph.dot`, and `example.dot`. You're basically running this command:

```
dot -Tpng foo.dot graph.dot example.dot > foo.png graph.png example.png
```

... which tells the shell to execute `dot -Tpng foo.dot graph.dot example.dot graph.png example.png` and redirect the output to `foo.png`.

---

You should instead teach `make` how to create a .png file from a .dot file:

```
%.png: %.dot
        dot -Tpng $< > $@
```

(`$<` and `$@` are so-called [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html); the `%.png: %.dot` thing is a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html).)

Then tell it that the `dot` target depends on all the .png files:

```
.PHONY: dot
dot: $(DOTPNG)
```

([`.PHONY`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html) tells `make` that `dot` is not really the name of a file, it's just a rule that triggers commands.)

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working but could you explain how this `$< > $@` and this `.PHONY: dot
dot: $(DOTPNG)` are working or what they actually doing?

Comment: @Krys Added links to the documentation.

Comment: Got it. Thank you again